# MongoDB Configuration File not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, replication, replicaset

I am on Windows 10 environment.
By default, My mongod.cfg file has a content which is as follows i.e

```
# mongod.conf

systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: c:\data\log\mongod.log

storage:
    dbPath: c:\data\db
```

By this when I will start MongoDB through CMD command i.e

```
net start mongodb
```

It will be running.

Now I have to use replica set and for that, I have to make some changes to configuration file i.e I have to add some piece of code for accessing the Replication i.e

```
# mongod.conf

systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: c:\data\log\mongod.log

storage:
    dbPath: c:\data\db

net:
   bindIp: 0.0.0.0
   port: 27017

replication:
   replSetName: test
```

after that when I start the service through command net start MongoDB it will return the error i.e

```
The service is not responding to the control function.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2186.
```

I am not sure what is this? If anyone has any Idea about that? How can I fix this? Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Check Windows Event Viewer and see what's happening there.

Comment: @Saleem There are so many things under Event Viewer. What Things I have to capture

Comment: System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  Service Control Manager 
   [ Guid]  {555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4} 
   [ EventSourceName]  Service Control Manager 
 
  - EventID 7000 

   [ Qualifiers]  49152 
 
   Version 0 
 
   Level 2 
 
   Task 0 
 
   Opcode 0 
 
   Keywords 0x8080000000000000 
 
  - TimeCreated

Comment: [ SystemTime]  2018-01-30T12:00:08.035574600Z 
 
   EventRecordID 837 
 
   Correlation 
 
  - Execution 

   [ ProcessID]  796 
   [ ThreadID]  908 
   Chanel System 
   Computer A-Machine 
 
   Security 
- EventData 

  param1 MongoDB 
  param2 %%1053 
   4D006F006E0067006F00440042000000

Comment: Have you tried typing `NET HELPMSG 2186` , as it suggests?